# How do I change the width of this Search Bar?

Tags: html, css, styles

It already has a prefixed width on the stylesheet but I have two different searchbars so I cannot modify that one, is there a way to override that width and change it to 200px? THanks

```
<div id="search-10" class="widget_search">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/?s=" onsubmit="window.location = action + s.value + '+: Cordoba'; return false;">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s2" id="s" style="margin-left:0px;">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see the `id` of your "search bar" which is actually called textbox is `s`

So you just have to put in you CSS

```
#s
{
    width:200px;
}
```

See a working example here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/hdm4Q/

Comment: Si, si funciono. Agregue eso y le cambie el nombre a #s2. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @Lisandro De nada! si podés después aceptá la respuesta, así los demás saben que funca (y me das 15 puntos jajaja) saludos!!

Comment: @Akinator bugger! I assumed searchbar was the container not the div.

Comment: @James Things that happen, but, just in case, `s` is the id of the textbox, not a `div`

Comment: @Akinator: You're a better man than me, i'd have never made that link.

Comment: @James lol don't worry you'll get round to it :) I just think it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your markup you have both the id and the class associated with the div.

Why don't you just make a rule in your stylesheets for the id and place it after the widget_search class?

e.g

```
#search-10 
{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Nope it still has the same size. I have no idea because I keep having so much problems with it